# How to demonstrate two variables are orthogonal with respect to the output in a 3-D Python dataset?

Tags: python, probability, hypothesis-testing, chi-square-test, test

I have a Python dataset with 300 samples and 3 columns: 2 independent integer variables `X,Y`  and the dependent continuous variable `F` (output).

The `X` variable can only take 3 values, but `Y`can take up to 1024 different values. Based on my sample, I want to demonstrate that if `X=x0` minimizes the output for a given  `Y=yi`, i.e. `x0=argmin_x F(x,yi)` so `F(x0,yi)<F(x1,yi)<F(x2,yi)`, then `F(x0,yj) < F(x1,yj) < F(x2,yj)` for all `y=yj` values.

How could I do this? I was thinking in converting values into probabilities and run a hypothesis test, but I am not very sure what test to implement and how in Python.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do that quite easily with pandas or numpy libraries, programming every step precisely.

For instance: (pseudo code for 2 ordered values)

```
x0 = 100000
x1 = x0 + 1

for i in range(0,len(y)):
   x_temp = F(x,  y[i])
   if x0<x_temp and x0<x1:
      x0=x_temp

   if x0>x_temp:
      x1 = x0
      x0 = xtemp
```

If you want a more precise code, I recommend adding a small data sample to your question.

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know to provide additional information.